Correct usage of @Observable and @MainActor
Say I have a simple view:
struct MyView: View {
    var viewModel = MyViewModel() //see error message below
    
    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.cats, id:\.id) { cat in
            Text(cat.name)
        }
        .task {
            await viewModel.fetchCats()
        }
    }
}

And a simple ViewModel:
import Observation

@Observable
class MyViewModel {
    var cats = [Cat]()
    let apiService = APIService()
    
    func fetchCats() async {
        do {
            self.cats = try await apiService.cats()
        } catch {
            
        }
    }
}

This seems to work fine. I do not get any "updating the UI from a background thread"-type errors, even though I'm not specifically dispatching to the main thread or using @MainActor. So my first question is, why is this the case? Are those not needed when using @Observable?
Second question - if we are still supposed to use @MainActor, how do we use it in combination with @Observable? If I add @MainActor below @Observable in the MyViewModel class, I get this error in the view (on the commented line):
Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context 


I still could not find an official answer to this, did you find it?

It happens to be fine because views are always evaluated on the main actor (body is explicitly annotated). In iOS 18 all of View will be officially annotated @MainActor.
The right thing to do here is to mark both @MainActor. In iOS 18, the one on View will be unneeded but will do no harm.

Thanks. But how come we get the purple "publishing changes from a background thread" warning/error when using ObservableObject/@Published, but not with @Observable when we do something like self.cats = try await apiService.cats() in the view model?

Just to add to Rob's excellent answer: the change of View using @MainActor is attached to Xcode 16, rather than iOS 18. This means it will take effect on iOS 17, 16, etc, as soon as you recompile with Xcode 16.

if views are always evaluated on the main thread, then why did it used to complain about @Published? Makes no sense

@erotsppa There is a difference between "happens to be true at runtime that they are evaluated on the main thread" and "defined at compile time that they must be evaluated on the main thread." Before iOS 18, it was the former, and the compiler could not prove it would always be true even though it happened to be. Prior to iOS 18, your own code could create Views on background threads, and the compiler can't know you don't. The SwiftUI system happens never to do so.

The point of .task is to avoid the need for an object, e.g.
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.apiService) var apiService
    @State var cats: [Cat]? = nil

    var body: some View {
        if let cats {
            List(cats) { cat in
                Text(cat.name)
            }
        }
        else {
            ContentUnavailableView {
                Label("No Cats", systemImage: "tray.fill")
            } description: {
                Text("New cats you receive will appear here.")
            }
            .task {
                cats = await apiService.fetchCats()
            }
        }
    }
}

